# is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’? Yet I'm using ->

Tags: c, struct, arrow-functions, double-pointer

I'm having trouble with pointers here. I get the error message `'g' is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?`
Even though I am using ->.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct set {
  // The amount of elements capable of being stored in the set
    int capacity;
  // The number of elements in the set
    int size;
    char *array;
};
typedef struct set set;
typedef struct gra
{
    set *Set;
} graph;

set *set_empty();
graph **make_graph(int nodes);

set *set_empty()
{
  set *s = malloc(sizeof(set));
  s->capacity = 0;
  s->size = 0;
  s->array = malloc(sizeof(char));
  return s;
}

graph **make_graph(int nodes)
{
  graph **g = calloc(nodes - 1, sizeof(graph));
  for (int i = 0; i< nodes; i++)
  {
    *g->Set[i] = set_empty();
  }
  return g;
}
int main()
{
  graph **g = make_graph(5);
}
```

I tried *(g)->Set[i], *(g->Set[i]) and other variations but I can't seem to spot my mistake nor fix it.

EDIT: Here's an updated version of make_graph

````
graph *make_graph(int nodes)
{
  graph *g = malloc(nodes * sizeof(graph));
  for (int i = 0; i< nodes; i++)
  {
    g->Set[i] = set_empty();
  }
  return g;
}```
Doesn't solve my pointer problem, but thought it's worth adding.
````

Comment: See [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: You might want `g[i]->Set = set_empty();`

Comment: The memory management and indirection level choices of `make_graph` seem highly suspect.

Comment: @273K I am familiar with this, but I don't see how I can point to `Set[I]` properly. I tried multiple bracket placements yet I still get the same error.

Comment: `calloc(nodes - 1, ...)` doesn't allocate the required number of nodes.

Comment: If you were familiar with the operator precedence, you would try `(*g)->`. It's wrong in any case, see my other comments.

Comment: @WhozCraig You referring to my use of Calloc or?

Comment: I'm referring to why `g` is a pointer to pointer in the first place. In fact, `g` doesn't even need to be dynamically allocated at all; only its `Set` member (and its ensuing `set` objects) need that luxury. Why is `g` a pointer to pointer to `graph` ? Side note: if you have a dynamic `set` pointer sequence in a `graph` object, you'd better also have a `size_t siz;` member that tracks how many slots wide `Set` is.

Comment: @WhozCraig Because I want to create a graph data structure that's implemented as a set. So a graph with 5 vertices and each vertex is a set data structure. That's why I wanted to allocate memory for struct `graph`, to create 5 `set`s and then use `set_empty` on all of them

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79775

Comment: @user3840170  That looks like an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly pay attention to your set_empty function. It returns a set pointer; meanwhile, the Set variable is declared as an array of Sets in the graph; therefore, you have to dereference the result of set_empty to be able to store it in Set[i]. Also, you should be careful with dereferencing the **g... Instead rewrite your make_graph function like this

```c
graph **make_graph(int nodes)
{
  graph **g = calloc(nodes - 1, sizeof(graph));
  for (int i = 0; i< nodes; i++)
  {
    (*g)->Set[i] = *set_empty();
  }
  return g;
}
```

This will solve the issue with the error: `'g' is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’`